# Meteor - insert array of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this Schema (using meteor-collection2):

```
Settings = new Mongo.Collection("settings");

var Schema = {};

Schema.Settings = new SimpleSchema({

user_id: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    settings_firm_name: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    settings_firm_primary_branch: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    settings_firm_employees_num: {
        type: Number,
        optional: false,
        min:1
    },
    settings_firm_address: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    settings_firm_email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: false,
    },
    settings_firm_web_page: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    settings_firm_contact_phone: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    settings_firm_fax: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
    },
    settings_firm_social: {
        type: [Object],
        optional: false,
    },

    "firm_social.$.name": {
        type: String
    },
    "firm_social.$.link": {
        type: String,
        regEx:SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url
    }
});
```

I want to add to my database data that is validated by this schema. settings_firm_social is array of object. That objects are created from three different input fields where each object have name and link fields. How can I insert that document in my database? I simply try with:

```
Settings.insert(settings, function(error,result){
 if(error){console.log(error)}

});
```

But my array then is populated with three empty objects ({}).

**EDIT**

When I log settings object that I pass to Meteor method befor insert:

```
I20150627-00:29:36.523(2)? Server log
I20150627-00:29:36.543(2)? { settings_firm_name: 'Test',
I20150627-00:29:36.543(2)?   settings_firm_primary_branch: 'test',
I20150627-00:29:36.543(2)?   settings_firm_employees_num: '200',
I20150627-00:29:36.543(2)?   settings_firm_address: 'Test',
I20150627-00:29:36.544(2)?   settings_firm_contact_phone: '12345',
I20150627-00:29:36.544(2)?   settings_firm_fax: '123445',
I20150627-00:29:36.544(2)?   settings_firm_web_page: 'http://localhost:3000/settings/ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF',
I20150627-00:29:36.544(2)?   settings_firm_email: 'test@hotmail.com',
I20150627-00:29:36.544(2)?   settings_firm_social:
I20150627-00:29:36.545(2)?    [ { name: 'Facebook',
I20150627-00:29:36.545(2)?        link: 'http://localhost:3000/settings/ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF' },
I20150627-00:29:36.545(2)?      { name: 'Twitter',
I20150627-00:29:36.546(2)?        link: 'http://localhost:3000/settings/ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF' },
I20150627-00:29:36.546(2)?      { name: 'LinkedIn',
I20150627-00:29:36.546(2)?        link: 'http://localhost:3000/settings/ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF' } ],
I20150627-00:29:36.546(2)?   user_id: 'ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF' }
```

After insert:

```
I20150627-00:31:23.185(2)? { settings_firm_name: 'Test',
I20150627-00:31:23.185(2)?   settings_firm_primary_branch: 'test',
I20150627-00:31:23.185(2)?   settings_firm_employees_num: 200,
I20150627-00:31:23.185(2)?   settings_firm_address: 'Test',
I20150627-00:31:23.185(2)?   settings_firm_contact_phone: '12345',
I20150627-00:31:23.186(2)?   settings_firm_fax: '123445',
I20150627-00:31:23.186(2)?   settings_firm_web_page: 'http://localhost:3000/settings/ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF',
I20150627-00:31:23.187(2)?   settings_firm_email: 'test@hotmail.com',
I20150627-00:31:23.187(2)?   settings_firm_social: [ {}, {}, {} ],
I20150627-00:31:23.187(2)?   user_id: 'ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF' }
```

Comment: can you add the content of the `settings` object you pass in your insert?

Comment: Nothing looks wrong in your settings object, as far as I know. Collection2 being based on Simple schema, you should enable debug mode as described here:https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#debug-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new schema object to validate settings_firm_social.

```
Schema.settings = new SimpleSchema({
  settings_firm_social: {
    type: [settingsFirmSocialSchema]
  }
});
```

And then:

```
var settingsFirmSocialSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  link: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

Comment: That is strange. Can you get rid of the 'firm_social.$.name' and 'firm_social.$.link' fields in the top level schema? Make sure settingsFirmSocialSchema is defined first in your file so it is not undefined. Also, how are you attaching this? Are you doing Settings.attachSchema(Schema) or Settings.attachSchema(Schema.settings)? It should be the latter

Comment: Your solution will work, I have two typo insted of firm_social.$.name it should be settings_firm_social.$.name. Same is for link field. And It seems that http://localhost:3000/settings/ZQwjxYzBuSfodxHvF is not valid URI. When I add www in front of localhost it will work. I can accept your answer with this sidenotes.